# What exactly is meant by standard state in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I was told that the standard enthalpy of a reaction is the enthalpy change when the reaction occurs with all reactants and products being in there standard states and under standard conditions(1 bar pressure for gases and 1molar concentration for solutions),but when we say 1 bar pressure for gases,do we mean that the partial pressure of each of the gaseous reactants and products is 1 bar,or that the total pressure of the reactants and products combined is 1 bar?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148106/discussion-on-question-by-aditya-mukherjee-what-exactly-is-meant-by-standard-sta); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.